# Units for displacement current density

Tags: electromagnetism

The displacement current density,
$$\mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \textbf{E}}{\partial t}$$

has units of (N/A^2) (C^2/Nm^2) N/Cs = Ns^2/(Cm^2)

which is not the same for current density:
C/sm^2

Where is the discrepancy?

Comment: I found my mistake.  How do I delete this?

Comment: ^ There should be a 'delete' button around here. Alternatively, you can post and accept the solution yourself.

Comment: I've flagged the question for a moderator to look at. Maybe he/she will delete it for you.

Comment: You can't delete it [because it has an upvoted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). But in this case, it's your answer, so you can delete the answer and then you should be able to delete the question. That being said, I think this is a good question and answer - even though it was caused by a minor mistake, someone else could easily make the same mistake, and leaving this post here would help them. (Plus, free rep :-P)

Comment: Well then.  I guess I'll just leave this here.

Answer (score 2):

It's cause $\mu_0$ is not part of the displacement current density.